# InDesign Double sided printing

Tags: adobe-indesign

I hope someone can help me. I designed a 4 page front and back card sized to 5x4 for a client. They want to print it front and back. I have the pages set up to printer spreads sized at 5x4. The pages look like this:
4, 1
2, 3

I created a PDF set up as above and sent it to them. But when printing both sides the inside pages (2,3) seems to be shifting and not aligning with the front (4,1). They are using double sided print and not manually turning the page to print the inside. Any idea why it would shift? Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, page duplexing is by flopping the image right-to-left; and sometimes by tumbling (flipping) the image top-to-bottom. Depending on the various settings, some mis-matched automatic settings compensate for one another with unexpected results.

Check the various printer settings to see that they match yours.

- Are the Printer settings okay?
- Are the presets okay?
- Is the Paper Size, Orientation, Scale okay? (no auto-rotation enabled)
- Are the host computer Print & Fax preferences okay?
- Is the Layout in the Print Dialog specified okay?
- Is the Paper Handling okay?
- Is the Paper Feed okay?
- Is 2-Sided Print or 2-Sided Print, Flip on Short Edge selected?